# How To Access ngCordova Camera Image From Inside JavaScript

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am currently developing a photo-editing app with the Ionic Framework. At the moment, I have used an open-source JS Drag & Drop photo editor and have modified accordingly but I need to be able to access the image that the user creates with the ngCordova Camera plugin outside of the AngularJS and in a separate script with only JS.

I've decided to take on the ( **angular.element(document.getElementById('editor')).scope().** ) approach but have come to no avail.

I'm starting to think that isn't going to be possible but that's why I came here to give it a final shot.

Here's some code from the editor. Yoda is the background image which works when set to a locally stored image.

```
        window.onload = function() {
       //THIS IS WHERE WE WILL ACCESS THE IMAGE GENERATED BY ngCamera

        var sources = {
            yoda: angular.element(document.getElementById('editor')).scope().pictureUrl
        };
        loadImages(sources, initStage);

    };
```

Below is where we take the picture and assign its url to $scope.pictureUrl. Ignore the adding to array part, that is for syncing the images to Firebase.

```
 $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options)
        .then(function(imageData) {
            syncArray.$add({image: imageData});
            $scope.pictureUrl= 'data:image/jpeg:base64,' + data
            .then(function() {
                alert("Image has been uploaded");
            });
        }, function(error) {
            console.error(error);
        });
  };
```

Pastebin for the whole app.js file: http://pastebin.com/8A8C4hL3

In brief, I am looking for a way to access an image created by ngCordova's Camera plugin inside of some actual JS and outside of the AngularJS used by the Ionic Framework.

Comment: Have you tried saving the image into `localStorage`?

Comment: How would I go about doing that? @mJunaidSalaat

Comment: Yeah sure. If its just you want your image in an external `js` file, then I guess its a good approach and definitely worth a try.

Comment: Can u do an answer please? @mJunaisSalaat

Answer (score 1):

If its just you want your image in an external js file, then you can try to store the image in **localStorage** like

```
$cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
          localStorage.setItem('myBase64Image', ("data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData));

        }, function(err) {
          console.log('error in camera then');
          // error
        });
```

Then in your external `js` file You can access your `base64` image like.

```
localStorage.getItem('myBase64Image')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, Thanks! But I was just wondering whether `localStorage.getItem('myBase64Image')` could be used just like a normal .png file and whether it would work outside of AngularJS?

Comment: Yes it would work outside `angular.js` environment because it is pure JavaScript. And yes you can save nornal `.png` to `localStorage` but by converting the image to base64 first then saving the base64 uri in `localStorage`.